# Why are my dependencies not replaced during my integration tests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Data Access project `DataAccess` with an Entity Framework Core `DbContext` defined:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyEntity> MyEntities { get; set; }
}
```

---

My web API project `Services` has a reference to `DataAccess` and the following in its `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<DataAccess.MyDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionStringName")));
}
```

(`_configuration` is an `IConfiguration` that is passed into the constructor of `Startup.cs` - not relevant to this discussion).

This project has a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` which itself has a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`.

---

Then I have a separate unit testing project `ServiceTests` that has a reference to `Services`, as well as a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` so that I can swap-out the SQL Server provider for an in-memory one.

The following integration test is defined:

```
public void MyIntegrationTest
{
    var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseEnvironment("Testing")
        .UseStartup<Services.Startup>()
        .ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataAccess.MyDbContext>(o => o.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDbName"));
        }));
    var dbContext = server.Host.Services.GetService<DataAccess.MyDbContext>();

    Assert.True(dbContext.MyEntities.Any(f => f.Bar == "quux"));
}
```

---

The problem is that this test blows up at `server.Host.Services.GetService<DataAccess.MyDbContext>()`, saying it cannot load `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll`. This is strange to me because my expectation is that the registration of the in-memory database should override the one for the SQL Server database, so there should be no need to load anything specific to SQL Server.

And even if there was such a need, `ServiceTests` references `Service` which loads `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll`, so I would expect that the latter would be transitively loaded if it was needed.

Can anyone advise as to where I'm going wrong? I've tried many suggestions, such as registering the test DbContext as a singleton, but nothing I've attempted is able to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Does the test project have a reference to `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll` ? This has more to do with what the main project has referenced, even if it is being overridden for the test

Comment: The test project becomes the composition root, which would need to reference all lower dependencies.

Comment: Have you tried having the test project reference the missing assembly?

Comment: The use of the SUT `Startup` class causes the context to initially be registered with the SQL Server provider. *Then* you simply override that registration to use the In Memory provider instead, but that doesn't override the dependency. You essentially now have a dependency on both, even though you're ultimately only using one. That said, you are correct that the SQL Server provider assembly should be coming through from the project reference. The only reason I can think of why that wouldn't happen is if there's a version conflict.

Comment: @Nkosi I don't **want** to reference `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in my test project because to my mind, there should be no need for it if the dependency replacement is occurring correctly.

Comment: @IanKemp I understand that. But have you tried it so we can rule it out? If it works then it proves what Chris said as accurate. Which I also agree with.

Comment: @Nkosi Yes, if I do that it works.

Comment: So essentially, I have to do something like `if (!_currentEnvironment.IsEnvironment("Testing")) services.AddDbContext<DataAccess.MyDbContext>(o => o.UseSqlServer(_configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionStringName")));` in my `Startup.cs` to prevent the dependency on `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll` from being required by my test project... which means my testing concerns now leak into my main application. Or, I have to accept that my test project loads (directly or indirectly) `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.dll`, which is not *its* concern. Ughhhhhh...

Comment: What you can do is use Startup method conventions for that. You can do `ConfigureIntegrationTestsServices` in your `Startup.cs` and register there your `InMemory` db. Take a look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2#startup-method-conventions. Then, in your test you don't need to call `ConfigureTestServices` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in .net7 and what eventually worked for me is this:

```
    builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        var serviceDescriptor1 = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(MyDbContext));
        var serviceDescriptor2 = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext>));
        var serviceDescriptor3 = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions));

        services.Remove(serviceDescriptor1);
        services.Remove(serviceDescriptor2);
        services.Remove(serviceDescriptor3);

        services.AddDbContext<IntegrationDbContext>(opt =>
        {
            opt.UseInMemoryDatabase("InMemoryDbForTesting");
        });
    });
```

There was no elegant way to de-register the original context, so it had to be done manually.
In my solution I use Cosmos, but it should be the same